# How to get data from the given JSON format using JsonUtility in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

```
{
"page": 2,
"per_page": 3,
"total": 12,
"total_pages": 4,
"data": [
    {
        "id": 4,
        "first_name": "Eve",
        "last_name": "Holt",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Morris",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "first_name": "Tracey",
        "last_name": "Ramos",
        "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
    }
]
```

}

The above JSON was format I tried to test.So I added it to a string but it was showing errors.so I edited it to the following code removed double quotes and added single quotes now error was gone.Not sure to use single or double quotes.

```
string JSONDataString;
JSONDataString = @"{
'page': 2,
'per_page': 3,
'total': 12,
'total_pages': 4,
'data': [
    {
        'id': 4,
        'first_name': 'Eve',
        'last_name': 'last_name',
        'avatar': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg'
    },
    {

        'id': 5,
        'first_name': 'Charles',
        'last_name': 'Morris',
        'avatar': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg'

    },
    {

        'id': 6,
        'first_name': 'Tracey',
        'last_name': 'Ramos',
        'avatar': 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg'

    }
]
}";
```

I used a @ at the start of the string.I do not know why I used it as I have seen in some examples.I removed all the double quotes and added single quotes.I created another class to handle the data from the JSON which is given below

```
public class DataHandler {


public int id;
public string firstname;
public string lastname;
public string avatar;

public DataHandler(int ID,string FName,string LName,string Avatar)
{
    this.id = ID;
    this.firstname = FName;
    this.lastname = LName;
    this.avatar = Avatar;

}


}
```

How to extract data from the first array and second array.First array elements means(page,per_page...total_pages) .Second array means(id,first_name,last_name,avatar from three groups)?

```
var obj = JsonUtility.FromJson<DataHandler>(JSONDataString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class representing the JSON is wrong.
See the correct representation below:

```
public class Datum
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string avatar { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int total_pages { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to mark your class as serializable.
Use the attribute:

```
[System.Serializable]
```

**Usage**

```
RootObject root=JsonUtility.FromJson<RootObject>(jsonString);
    foreach(var item in root.data){
    Debug.Log(item.id);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure,I somewhere read you cant use get set with JsonUtility

Comment: Well, that is, in my opinion, the valid representation of the JSON. I don't think getting rid of the get set will have any negative effect. That's just the way Unity works.

Comment: I'm not too sure. Why don't you just read your data from a text file?. That way, you won't have to worry about manipulating the JSON string.

Comment: Error is coming "ArgumentException: JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member. UnityEngine.JsonUtility."

Comment: How did you try to deserialise the JSON?

Comment: How to get values from the 'data'......... I used the following line but not working.....Debug.Log("List Data " + obj.data[0].id );

Comment: Did you use double quotes? This should be easy. What is the error?

Comment: As you said i removed it uploaded in server that would be easy....Error "ArgumentException"  was gone.....Now I want to fetch info from the 'data' field. public List<Datum> data { get; set; }

Comment: I did not use System.Serilizable....but when I used it in top of two classes...I got it.thanks..How does [System.Serializable] help here?

Comment: It helps Unity to better understand the structure of the class, for better serialisation or deserialisation. You can read more on it! Mark as accepted if this answer helped you. Have a nice time!

Answer (score 0):

Your class that represent object is not right. You can generate a class from json in the visual studio "Edit > Paste special > Paste JSON as Classes".

In you case it's:

```
public class Rootobject
    {
        public int page { get; set; }
        public int per_page { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
        public int total_pages { get; set; }
        public Datum[] data { get; set; }
    }

    public class Datum
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string first_name { get; set; }
        public string last_name { get; set; }
        public string avatar { get; set; }
    }
```

Your "JSONDataString" json string looks good so just use "Newtonsoft.Json" nuget to parse the object:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
```